# Invalid hook statement, conversion to work with class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export class Register extends Component {

  render() {


====>  const [selectedGoal, setSelectedGoal] = React.useState(1);

    const goal = [
      {
        label: "Muscle Gain",
        id: 1,
      },
      {
        label: "Fat Loss",
        id: 2,
      },
      {
        label: "Maintaining",
        id: 3,
      },
    ];

    const details = [
      {
        label: "1 pound per week",
      },
      {
        label: "0.5 pounds per week",
      },
      {
        label: "0.25 pounds per week",
      },
    ];
    return (
      <SafeAreaView
        style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "white", alignItems: "center" }}
      >
        <ProgressSteps
          progressBarColor="red"
          activeStepIconBorderColor="red"
          completedProgressBarColor="red"
          completedStepIconColor="red"
          activeLabelColor="red"
        >
          <ProgressStep>
            <View/>
          </ProgressStep>
          <ProgressStep>
            <View>
            </View>
          </ProgressStep>
          <ProgressStep>
            <View style={{ alignItems: "center" }}>
 ====>        <RadioButtonRN
                boxStyle={{
                  height: hp("6%"),
                  width: wp("80%"),
                }}
                activeColor="white"
                boxActiveBgColor="red"
                textColor="black"
                textStyle={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}
                data={goal}
                initial={selectedGoal}
                selectedBtn={(e) => setSelectedGoal(e.id)}
              />
            </View>
          </ProgressStep>
          <ProgressStep
            label="Details"
            onSubmit={() => this.functionCombined()}
            nextBtnTextStyle={{ color: "red" }}
            previousBtnTextStyle={{ color: "red" }}
            finishBtnText="Finish"
          >
            {selectedGoal == 1 ? (
              <View style={{ alignItems: "center" }}>
                <Text style={{ color: "red", fontSize: 15, top: hp("5%") }}>
                  How much would you like to gain per week?
                </Text>
                <RadioButtonRN
                  style={{ top: hp("10%") }}
                  boxStyle={{
                    height: hp("6%"),
                    width: wp("80%"),
                  }}
                  activeColor="white"
                  boxActiveBgColor="red"
                  textColor="black"
                  textStyle={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}
                  data={details}
                  selectedBtn={(e) => console.log(e)}
                />
              </View>
            ) : selectedGoal == 2 ? (
              <View>
                <Text>Ciao</Text>
              </View>
            ) : (
              <View>
                <Text> you made it</Text>
              </View>
====>         )}
          </ProgressStep>
        </ProgressSteps>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}
export default Register;
```

Hey everyone, I'm trying to convert a function component to a class component in order to work with this progress step registration page and radio buttons, the idea is to have a radio button, and depending on the result of that radio button, to show a different View component with another radio button

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use hooks inside class components: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#should-i-use-hooks-classes-or-a-mix-of-both

You will need to use the class state method: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-local-state-to-a-class